# Does the refresh token need to be set explicitly in Spartacus?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

In my Sparatacus 2.0 application, my APIs are getting invalidated after the access_token times out and gives this error.

```
 {
    "error":"invalid_token",
    "error_description":"Invalid access token: 14399ab4-2e63-4ee2-a0a8-3ff493e09142"
 }
```

The authentication response after login is this

```
{
  "access_token" : "14399ab4-2e63-4ee2-a0a8-3ff493e09142",
  "token_type" : "bearer",
  "refresh_token" : "5c28d5b1-c978-4e38-adfa-c1e41ef97b9c",
  "expires_in" : 13,
  "scope" : "basic openid"
}
```

Do I need to explicitly set the refresh token in the frontend by calling some OOTB Spartacus method?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in Spartacus 3.0 . The refresh token was only stored (in the memory) as long I was in the same browser tab after the login, when I refreshed the page the user was only authenticated until the access token expired.

The issue for me was that the `AuthStatePersistenceService` was not saving the refresh token in the local storage and because of that it was not anymore there after a page reload. I was able to fix it with overwriting the `getAuthState` function in this service like that:

```
import { combineLatest, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthStatePersistenceService, SyncedAuthState } from '@spartacus/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyAuthStatePersistenceService extends AuthStatePersistenceService {
  /**
   * Gets and transforms state from different sources into the form that should
   * be saved in storage.
   */
  protected getAuthState(): Observable<SyncedAuthState> {
    return combineLatest([
      this.authStorageService.getToken().pipe(
        filter((state) => !!state),
        map((state) => {
          return {
            ...state,
          };
        }),
      ),
      this.userIdService.getUserId(),
      this.authRedirectStorageService.getRedirectUrl(),
    ]).pipe(
      map(([authToken, userId, redirectUrl]) => {
        let token = authToken;

        if (token) {
          token = { ...token };
        }

        return { token, userId, redirectUrl };
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Maybe that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There was an existing issue with spartacus and it’s been fixed.

If you want to fix this issue just update  https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/pull/4443/commits/0cbf839ca4b6dda195730a81fcce5881bc70be39#diff-f13978c59296903fbcc824e50a0563fbf3dc1583b818c3769d0e1f84fc99d036
According to this commit.